# PHP DateTime output an array of dates in range

Tags: php, datetime

I am calculated the date in 6 months time like this...

```
$date = new DateTime('01/02/2019');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P6M'));
echo $date->format('d/m/Y') . "\n";
```

This is working as far as I can tell, does anybody know of a way to get it to output an array of dates in this new period?

Does DateTime have anything built in?

Comment: You want an array of dates between those days? There's no such function or method, but you can build it yourself.

Comment: what is your php version , your code in fine , it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop through all the dates, as there is no native function to do this.

You can create a loop that would append each date to an array, and increment the date until it reaches the end-date.

```php
function get_interval($startDate, $endDate) {
    $result = [];
    while ($startDate < $endDate) {
        $currentDate = (clone $startDate);
        $result[] = $currentDate;
        $startDate->modify("+1 day");
    }
    return $result;
}
$date = new DateTime('01/02/2019');
$enddate = (clone $date)->add(new DateInterval('P6M')); // Note that the object is cloned
                                                        // Otherwise we modify the original $date
print_r(get_interval($date, $enddate));
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/aLf5o

Comment: That is returning the correct number of days but the start_date that is being written to the array is not changing

Comment: I can't reproduce that behavior.. https://3v4l.org/Om0ug  `modify("+1 day")` is clever, and adds one day. If that changes the month or year, it does so accordingly.

Comment: Ignore last comment, was my fault. All working now, thanks for the help